# Making promise wait for another promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Within a node.js app, I'm trying to look up a list of products from an API, then get the thumbnail image for the first item only.

Within my code getOrderDetails is a promise, and then if it's the first product, it calls function getImage which is also a promise.

However when I run the code the orderDetails is populated without the thumbnail - so it looks like the code isn't waiting for the getImage function to resolve.

Please can someone explain what I have done wrong?

Thank you in advance!

```
if (siteConfig.storeIntegration == 'Cart') {

    getOrderDetails(restPathOrder)
    .then(function(res) {

        var orderDetails = '';

        for (i = 0; i < res.items.length; i++) {

            productId = res.items[i]['productId'];

            thumbnail = '';

            if (i == 0) {

                getImage(productId, restApiKey)
                .then(function(res) {

                    thumbnail = res;

                    console.log('thumbnail:' + res);
                })
            }

            orderDetails = orderDetails + res.items[i]['quantity'] + ',' + res.items[i]['name'] + ',' + productUrl + ',' + thumbnail;

        }

        console.log(orderDetails);

    })


}

function getOrderDetails(restPath) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        request(restPath, function (error, response, body) {

            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                restData = JSON.parse(body);

                resolve(restData)
             }
        })
    })


}

function getImage(productId, restApiKey) {

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        var restPathProduct = storeURL + restApiKey + productId;

        request(restPathProduct, function (error, response, body) {

            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

                restData = JSON.parse(body);

                thumbnail = restData.image[0];

                resolve(thumbnail);
             }
        })
    })

}
```

Comment: You cannot assign to `thumbnail` from an asynchronous callback. Btw, you forgot to declare your variables (`i`, `thumbnail`, `restdata`) as local with `var`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might I suggest using new [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) syntax?

```
async main() {
    if (siteConfig.storeIntegration == 'Cart') {
        let res = await getOrderDetails(restPathOrder);

        var orderDetails = '';

        for (i = 0; i < res.items.length; i++) {

            productId = res.items[i]['productId'];

            let thumbnail = '';

            if (i == 0) {
                thumbnail = await getImage(productId, restApiKey);
            }

            orderDetails += res.items[i]['quantity'] + ',' + res.items[i]['name'] + ',' + productUrl + ',' + thumbnail;
        }
        console.log(orderDetails);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@FrankerZ is right that async/await makes the code much cleaner.

I'm unsure on your business logic, where productUrl comes from.

The solution is to wrap the whole block of code in a promise, get the image for the first order, and in the `then` of getImage, then you can process the order details.

Here is my attempt, with some minor refactors. Hopefully it can steer you in the right direction.

```
function process() {
  // Wrap everything inside a promise, we then resolve with the order details
  // Resolve is what gets returned in the .then((resolvedData)), reject is what gets returned in the .catch((rejectedThings))
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // Get the order details
    getOrderDetails(restPathOrder)
      .then(function(orderRes) {

        // Handle no items
        if (!orderRes.items || orderRes.items.length === 0) {
          return reject("No items") // You can deal with this in the catch
        }
        // Get first item 
        const firstOrder = orderRes.items[0];

        // Fetch the first thumbnail then proceed to fetch the rest of the order details. 
        getImage(firstOrder.productId, restApiKey)
          .then(function(thumbnail) {

            let orderDetails = '';
            // Build order details body
            // N.B I'm not sure how you want orderDetails to appear, personally I would use a map instead of a forEach. 
            orderRes.items.forEach((item) => {
              orderDetails = orderDetails + item.quantity + ',' + item.name + ',' + productUrl + ',' + thumbnail;
            })

            // Then resolve with the order details
            return resolve(orderDetails);
          })
      })
  })
}

// You can then call process as a promise with the order details
process().then(function(orderDetails) => console.log(orderDetails))
```

Comment: I like your getImage outside the loop, although I just realized it's going to append thumbnail on each iteration.